# Issue deploying site template to subsite

Tags: site, collection

I have exported a Sharepoint 2013 subsite to a .wsp file and uploaded to a new site collection. I have enabled this on the new site collection. When trying to create a new subsite, the template does not appear under "template selection". The only category available on here is "Collaboration" but from screenshots of other's Sharepoint sites I can see that they have other options available here.

I have read that I need to enable the template after creating the subsite. Which is apparently located under "Page Layouts and Site Templates" under "Look and Feel". I do not have this option. Under Look and Feel I have the following on my subsite:

Title, description, and logo - Quick Launch - Top Link Bar

No other options are available. I am the site collection admin, but I am not the admin for sharepoint and cannot make my own site collections. Am I missing features that I need to enable in order to utilize a template on a subsite?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you enabled Publishing feature at the Site Collection Level?

Comment: The "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" option does not appear in my SharePoint site collection site settings. My guess is the company has locked down a lot of features. I'm waiting to hear back from them regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are missing some Site collection features. Go to the homepage of the root site collection (it doesn't have to be the home page but that ensures you are in the right place) and navigate:

Settings > Site Settings > Site Collection Administration > Site Collection Features.

Check that Publishing, Community Site and Project Site Features are enabled. If they are not click Enable for all of them. This should enable all the templates at the Site Collection level.

If you find the features are already enabled then the templates are propbably out-of-scope for subsites.

Navigate:

Site settings > Page layout and site template settings > Subsite templates

Check the box marked "Subsites can only use the following site templates" the add the templates you want and try to create your subsite again

Comment: I don't have this option either unfortunately, The only Site Collection related items under "Site Collection Administration" are "Site collection app permissions", "Site collection health checks", and "site collection upgrade". I guess I may need to get in touch with the central admins to have these features enabled?

Comment: If you aren't the site collection administrator I'm afraid you are out of luck. you need to have a word with your sysadmins about either getting the access rights you need or having them enable the features for you.

Comment: I am the "site collection administrator" as per the settings on the site collection, but I am at a large corporation and it seems they lock me out of a lot of things. I am contacted them regarding the options you specified to see if they can give me access to them.